# Where can I find biographical details on Bernardino (Dino) Barozzi?

Tags: art, italy, nobility, biography

I am studying some specific aristocratic merchants figures in Italian history and nobilty and I came across the figure of Bernardino (Dino) Barozzi. Dates of birth and death are 1863 and 1942. Any other reference may be related to a homonymous Barozzi (some references are indeed about the father). Very little is know about him and I would like to ask here if any of you would be able to give a detailed biography (even references would be a good proxy for an answer, even about Italian nobility of that period as well) of this rather obscure aristocratic figure of the late XIX century.

Comment: @SonGohan  I've updated your question with the information you provided in comments. Best practice is to include _all_ the information and prior research you have in the question.

Comment: A little family info [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=kLgTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA183&dq=Bernardino+Barozzi+1863&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS5cn87qzyAhXkN30KHQJfCCEQ6AEwCXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=Bernardino%20Barozzi%201863&f=false)

Comment: @justCal thank you very much! This is indeed his family and this is really useful information! Any reference of this kind (yearbooks of noble families, ...) is very appreciated! (by the way: do you think it may be a more suitable question for the "Genealogy & Family History" stack exchange? I thought about "History" since I am mostly interested into the figure of himself rather than the whole family, but still...)

Comment: [Genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help you if you have specific details you are trying to fill in. Some existing questions such as [this](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/where-to-find-list-of-census-performed-in-italy) or [this](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/is-there-a-single-place-i-could-go-in-italy-to-view-birth-records-from-northern) might give you clues on where to begin looking for more information.

Comment: @justCal, if you convert your comment as an answer, I will award the bounty to you since no other answer popped up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a little information which seems to match the individual you are asking about, matching the name and birth date given.  A search through 19th century works came up with a hit in the 1889 *[Annuario della nobiltà italiana](https://books.google.com/books?id=kLgTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA183&dq=Bernardino%20Barozzi%201863&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS5cn87qzyAhXkN30KHQJfCCEQ6AEwCXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=Bernardino%20Barozzi%201863&f=false)*
.

[image]

This seems to give a simple family list. Letting Google attempt to translate the clip has the following *interesting* results:

> Barozzi Relig Cattolica Resid Venezia Nicolò nob Barozzi patr Venetian
> n 18 Oct 1826 doctor in law director of the Civic Museum of Venice son
> of the nobles Bernardino Alvise n 19 December 1789 7 and noble Teresa
> born of the Counts Merati 1874 married in 1861 to the noble Natalia
> born baroness Knorring from Petersburg Children 1 Bernardino Alvise n
> in 1863 2 Pietro Orseolo 1 in 1864 3 Teresa born 4 Elisa born

---

Here's my translation of the translation.

**Family:**

Barozzi, Catholics that resided in the city of Venice.

**Grandparents:**

- Bernardino Alvise Barozzi, born 19 December 1789 , died unk.
- Teresa born of the Counts Merati. She died in 1874

**Parents:**

- Nicoloa Barozzi of Venice was born 18 Oct 1826. Doctor of Law, and
  director of Civic Museum in Venice. Married in 1861 to
- Natalia, born baroness Korring of Petersberg. (no dates)

**Children of Nicola and Natalia:**

1. ***Bernardino Alvise born in 1863***
2. Pietro Orseolo born in 1864
3. Teresa born
4. Elisa born